# AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE (Line 7;Position 51)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

This is my XAML code in my project, in this first i display MainListBox then display ChatListBox depending on user selection. When user select to chat then i got run time Xaml parseing exception.

this is my whole Xaml code...

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="DocomoMessenger.View.Buddies"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="126"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="580*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2,2,0,2">
        <ProgressBar Height="3" Name="waitprogess" Margin="0,2,0,0" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtload" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,5,12,0" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="1,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,0,2,0">
        <Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="DarkGray" CornerRadius="10" Name="buddyborder">
                <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Height="100" >
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding IM}" Stretch="Fill" Width="50" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></Image>
                                <StackPanel Margin="1,4,0,0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="details" Height="100">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Foreground="Brown" Padding="10"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusMsg}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="10" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <Image Tag="{Binding Name}" Source="{Binding IMChat}" Grid.Column="2" Stretch="Uniform" Width="40" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="imgchat"  MouseLeftButtonUp="imgchat_MouseLeftButtonUp"></Image>
                                <Line Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Stroke="DarkGray" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="0,10,0,0" X1="10" Y1="10" Y2="10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
        </Border>

        <ListBox x:Name="ChatListBox" Margin="2,2,0,0" Opacity="1" Visibility="Collapsed" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Name="megrid" Margin="3,5,0,0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding FirstCol}"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding LastCol}"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Name="imgbud" Source="{Binding IM}" Grid.Column="{Binding ImgCol}" Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Uniform" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                        <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="2" RadiusY="20" RadiusX="20" Grid.Column="{Binding RectCol}" Fill="{Binding Bru}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="{Binding RectCol}" Padding="10" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="{Binding RectCol}" Padding="10" />
                        <Path Data="{Binding Obj}" Fill="{Binding Bru}" Margin="0,0,-5,0" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorAlig}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="sendmsg" Height="75" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <TextBox Name="txtmsg" Text="type" Padding="5" Opacity="0.8" MouseLeftButtonUp="txtmsg_MouseLeftButtonUp" Width="370" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <Image Name="imgsend" Width="100" Height="46" Source="/DocomoMessenger;component/Themes/send.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0,12,4,17" MouseLeftButtonUp="imgsend_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

<!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
<!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
```

when I run this code i got following XamlParsinException error.
[image]

[image]

Anyone help me.
Thanks in Advance
Pavan.

Comment: Could you click "View Detail..." and have a look at any InnerException? (They might be nested) Just add them to your question.

Comment: Could you add the XAML to the question that precedes the Grid?

Comment: Hi Erno, I posted whole Xaml code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't pin it down, it is a nearly generic message that doesn't say much.

Here is what I would do:

1. Comment out all content so you are left with `<PhoneApplicationPage ...>`
2. Comment out all C# code that depends on the XAML you just commented out
3. Make sure the application compiles.
4. Now slowly, step by step, add xaml elements back in. Until you find the offending line.

If 4. is too hard you could reverse this trick; comment **out** part by part.

Comment: the problem in ChatListBox, ibut i dont knowwhere it is. so help me

Comment: Repeat the process for the DataTemplate and let us know.

Comment: The error is binding the GridLength to <ColumnDefinition width="{Binding FirstCol}".  It is worked in windows phone 7.1 but not working in windows phone 7. I don't know Why?

Comment: No, It worked in windows phone 7.1 but not working in windows phone 7.0

Comment: They probably fixed it in the new release. Why are you targeting windows phone 7? AFAIK all phones will run 7.1

Answer (score 0):

whats in your PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded method?

apart from a missing end tag

```
   </phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

in your snippet above I was able to build and run this in WP7 7.1.  I did have to omit your Loaded and MouseLeftButtonUp refers though as I don't have your full code.

Comment: No, i findout the problem i.e., i bind ({Binding FirstCol}) column width to ChatListBox. i solved my problem using "Auto". anyway thanks your respose. sorry to my english